# What does the phrase 時とタイミング mean?

Tags: meaning

It came up in a game (in the sentence ううん、これも時とタイミングですね。) and when I tried to look it up on different Japanese dictionary- and phrase-type sites, nothing came up, and when I looked around on Twitter to see if I could glean the context, I still didn't understand from peoples' posts, though they used it as what seemed to be a common phrase. It seemed to sometimes be used in ways like "if I have time and if the timing is right / if I have the opportunity (then we can meet up)," but in this context, it didn't seem right. Maybe that is also incorrect, though, as I am not fluent.

Is there possibly any way for some ways that it is used to be given in varying contexts, if anyone would have a moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

時とタイミングですね just means "It's about timing" or "It depends on when". これも時とタイミングですね means "It also depends on when". タイミングによります would be more explicit.

I don't call 時とタイミング a fixed set phrase, but I do hear it sometimes. Here 時 and タイミング refer to almost the same thing, so it's probably an example of [tautology](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-tautology.html) for emphasis, like "first and foremost".